# Execute a URL once application starts up on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a webapp which runs on Tomcat.

Initial login to the application from the web takes some time as the caches get warmed up. Subsequent logins are fast.

So we wanted to automate the first login to the application once the application starts up, so when users login they will not see the delay.

I tried creating a listener servlet to access the login URL of the application, but that does not seem to work as the application does not seem to be completely loaded.

Is there any other way for me to automate this on Tomcat itself so that once the application loads up I can execute its login URL?